# Provide Custom Alignment to ul-li elements

Tags: html, css

The HTML, CSS is available in the link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/td5ruzh7/6/

I need to utilize the space shown under small sized `ul` elements and make the `ul` elements shown below each `ul` element to move upwards. Please see the screenshots for the current arrangement and the required one below.

Or if you can give me some better option to do so, please let me know.

**current arrangement**:
[image]
**required arrangement:**
[image]

Comment: You can't make it in rows, you need to make it with columns. So category 1 and category 5 will be in the same box (column). This have so many problems, specially to construct an html layout without brokenbrain.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have four categorys in one row, try this:

```
  <div>
        <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 1</label></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>    
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 5</label></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 9</label></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 2</label></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 6</label></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 10</label></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 3</label></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 7</label></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 11</label></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 4</label></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 8</label></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li> <label> Category 12</label></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Merchant2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div div.col {
    float: left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the HTML structure. Anyway, thank you for your efforts :)